# How can I remove the Place Order button on Payment Method step on checkout page based on some condition - BigCommerce?

Tags: javascript, button, settimeout, bigcommerce

I want to restrict order placement if there minimum quantity conditions for items in cart for B2B customers is violated.

For this what I have done so far on checkout page:

```
    {{{ footer.scripts }}}
 
<script>
    var minQuantityEr = false;
</script>
 
{{#each cart.items}}
    {{#lt this.quantity 15}}
        <script>
            minQuantityEr = true;
        </script>
    {{/lt}}
{{/each}}
 
<script src="//unpkg.com/xhook@latest/dist/xhook.min.js"></script>
<script>
var wholeseller = false;
xhook.after(function(request, response) {
    if(request.url.match(/\/internalapi\/v1\/checkout\/customer$/)) 
    {  
        if(status = 200) 
        {
            var customerVar = JSON.parse(response.data);
            if(customerVar.data.customer.customerGroupName  == 'Wholesellers')
            {
                wholeseller = true;
            }
        } 
    }
});
 
xhook.after(function(request, response) {
    if(request.url.match(/\/api\/storefront\/payments$/)) 
    {  
        if(status = 200)
        {
            if(wholeseller)
            {
                if(minQuantityEr)
                {
                    alert('Each Item in cart should have 15 as minimum quantity.');
                    setTimeout(function(){ 
                        var elem = document.getElementById("checkout-payment-continue");
                        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
                    }, 500);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
 
{{/partial}}
```

I have used javascript method setTimeOut here to remove the Place Order button but its not a safe way as it might cause issues in case of slow internet speed and 500 miliseconds is not enough to detect the presence and remove the button.

Please suggest any other way around to detect the Place Order button on payment method step without using setTimeOut method.

Answer (score 1):

So if the rule is there must be at least 15 of each item in the cart, you could use assignVar, something like the following (not tested). You would need to update any template that shows the cart, I'd suggest making a "cart buttons" component that you use in all of them.

```
{{assignVar "allowOrder" true}}
{{#each cart.items}}
  {{#lt this.quantity 15}}
    {{assignVar "allowOrder" false}}
  {{/lt}}
{{/each}}

{{#all cart.show_primary_checkout_button allowOrder}}
   <a href="{{urls.checkout.single_address}}" class="button button--primary">...
{{/all}}

{{#unless allowOrder}}
  <p>order more stuff</p>
{{/unless}
```